# elegant way to iterate and count a sequence in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Let's have a pandas DataFrame of values 0 or 1 such as:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], columns=['instance'])
```

I am counting the occurrence of the 1 values with a reset of the count as a 0 comes up.  For example:

```
count, b = 0, []
for i in a.instance:
    if i == 0:
        count = 0
        b.append(count)
    else:
        count+=1
        b.append(count)
```

which gives me:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['count_check'])
c = pd.concat((a, b), axis=1)
```

results:

```
    instance  count_check
0          1            1
1          1            2
2          1            3
3          0            0
4          0            0
5          0            0
6          1            1
7          1            2
8          1            3
9          1            4
10         0            0
11         1            1
12         1            2
13         1            3
14         1            4
15         1            5
16         0            0
17         0            0
18         1            1
19         1            2
```

It works fine, but is a little slow for larger data sets and when it is repeated. Would there be a faster more elegant way to do the same?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a['count_check'] =  a.apply(lambda x: x.groupby((~x.astype(bool)).cumsum()).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
    instance  count_check
0          1            1
1          1            2
2          1            3
3          0            0
4          0            0
5          0            0
6          1            1
7          1            2
8          1            3
9          1            4
10         0            0
11         1            1
12         1            2
13         1            3
14         1            4
15         1            5
16         0            0
17         0            0
18         1            1
19         1            2
```